# What is the difference between different rarities of the same item in Apex Legends?

Tags: apex-legends

In Apex Legends, I've sometimes found multiple copies of the same item in a game, but with their names/frames appearing in different colours. I assume this represents different rarities. For example, I know I've picked up a "Wingman" revolver whose frame appeared in yellow, to replace another "Wingman" whose frame appeared in teal.

Based on other games, I assumed yellow was the "highest-quality" version of the weapon. However, the game interface doesn't seem to display any damage or rate-of-fire statistics for different weapons, or name the rarities, so I'm not confident that I'm doing the right thing.

How much difference is there between different rarities (colors) of the same weapon in Apex Legends, and how do they rank from best to worst?

Comment: Something the answers don't mention is weapons only appear as standard white items, or "fully-kitted" gold items which rarely appear in hot zones or dropped from random loot robots. The "teal" color you mention is just the color of the ammo type it uses, and will instead be golden if the weapon was found that way. The Mastiff and Kraber are exceptions as they only drop as golden from supply crates.

Comment: I also noticed, on skinned weapons you see the rarity of the skin with the corresponding color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this guide](https://www.dexerto.com/apex-legends/beginners-guide-to-apex-legends-battle-royale---ping-system-reviving-banners-movement-tips-inventory-more-336966) and [ign](https://m.ign.com/wikis/apex-legends/Weapons), gold is indeed the rarest color for weapons. The ranking is as follows:

> The color scheme used in Apex Legends can be a powerful tool once you get familiar with it. The colors represent item rarity with gray being the least rare, then blue, then purple, and finally gold being the rarest.
>   Loot dropped by eliminated players will glow the color of the rarest
>   item that it's in the stash, making it easier for you to decide which
>   stash to loot first.

There aren’t different tiers/rarities of individual weapons i.e. there aren’t grey, blue, and purple prowlers, but there are tiers for wearables and attachments.

For attachments, the higher the tier/rarity,  the better it is. Clips of higher rarity hold more ammo, stabilizers of higher rarity give more recoil control,  stocks of higher rarity provide faster raise/lower times when swapping weapons,  etc. The only subjectivity comes with scopes where it depends on preference as higher tier scopes have more zoom and gold scopes have the added benefit of highlighting enemies in red and showing enemies through smoke.

Gold weapons are the exact same as non-gold versions, except they come fully kitted with attachments that cannot be swapped out. There are also two gold weapons (Kraber and Mastiff) which can only be found in care packages and will always be gold.

Gold wearables are essentially equivalent to their purple counterparts, except they provide an additional passive perk.

- Gold helmet: faster recharge of abilities.
- Gold armor: full shield refresh on execution of an enemy.
- Gold backpack: faster usage of healing consumables.
- Gold knockdown shield: single use self-revive.

Comment: Good references. I've seen some comments elsewhere claiming that the only there are only two rarities of gun -- normal and gold -- and other colouring is only the result of the mods they have attached. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @Badeline hmm, hadn’t seen anything about that in my research, but I did see somewhere that the ui should inform you of the weapon you are looking at is better than the one you are carrying. It’s a new game, so there might be bugs/changes. I’ll try and update if anything changes

Comment: I believe that some weapons don't exist as whites, but only as gold weapons, like the Kraber. I only found it once and it was golden

Comment: If you find a 'fully kitted' weapon in a hot zone it is gold too.

Comment: It is gold, because the attachements are golden. I haven't tried it as of now, but I believe as soon as you remove those attachments and drop the weapon, it should drop as white one

Comment: @Dragonrage this guide has since been outdated by some of the changes EA has made since the publishing of this answer. Perhaps update it?

Answer (score 2):

**Loot colors indicate levels**

White - Blue - Purple - Gold

- Level 1 - White
- Level 2 - Blue
- Level 3 - Purple
- Level 4 - Gold

> Gold level 4 armor and gear in Apex Legends is rare but it exists. It's basically the same as purple level 3 but comes with perks:

- Gold helmet - faster tactical and ultimate cooldowns
- Gold armor -refills shields after an execution
- Gold backpack - fasterhealth/consumable use
- Gold Knockdown shield - self revive once

**The color also applies on different aspects of the game eg. shooting damage indicator.**

> The colour of damage numbers tells you about your enemy

- Red numbers means your opponent has no armor
- White numbers indicate level one armor
- Blue numbers show level two armor
- Purple numbers show level three armor
- Yellow numbers indicate a headshot

[source](https://www.gamesradar.com/apex-legends-tips/)

Comment: I believe yellow numbers also indicate level 4 armor as I am sure, that I don't perform that many headshots

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yellow numbers definitely also indicate yellow armor (besides headshots)